# How to show AWS CodeDeploy deployment on Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-code-deploy

Using Grafana's CloudWatch data source and a little InfluxDB magic, I can pull many metrics from my live environment; like CPU utilisation, memory utilisation, host count, thread count, ect etc.

These metrics will make more sense if I can spot the moments of live deployments on that graph.*ELB Health Host Count* metric kinda helps but does not show deployments, rather shows auto scale activities.

I can't find any metrics in AWS CloudWatch adapter for CodeDeploy. Dooes anybody has a way of doing this?

(My Env: Sprint Boot app on Docker containers deployed on AWS Fargate using CodeDeploy)

Answer (score 0):

You can push datapoints into a CloudWatch metric using the "put-metric-data" aws cli call [1]. You can call this command from the AppSpec file hooks like BeforeInstall and AfterInstall. Make sure the EC2 instance role has the requisite permissions.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-server